# Suitable way to write an maths formula

Tags: php

I have a formula that works out how to work out a betting accumulator.

The formula is :

> Stake x ( Fractional Odds + 1 ) x ( Fractional Odds + 1 ) etc...

I am looking to write a PHP function that loops through the odds and then returns the value.

I have an array as follows (Contains fractional odds)...

```
$odds = array(
'8/15',
'11/2',
'13/2',
'7/2'
);
```

Some example PHP code, That shows how I can do this (without a function)...

```
$result = 10 * (8/15 + 1) * (11/2 + 1) * (13/2 + 1) * (7/2 + 1);
echo number_format($result,2); // 3,363.75
```

and my stake is set as '10' for now.

What I need to do is loop through the odds array and multiply them by the brackets and to start with multiply by the Stake so for this is test case is 10.

Can anyone suggest a way to write this? When I do try write in * I keep getting PHP errors.

If the topic is not suitable for the community, Please state and I'll remove.

Thanks

Comment: you should use a foreach loop, and maybe wrap all of this in a function to simplify your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
function compute ($stake, $values) {
    $result = $stake;

    foreach ($values as $val)
    {
        $parts = explode('/', $val);
        $result *= ($parts[0] / $parts[1] + 1);
    }

    return $result;
}


$stake = 10;
$odds = array (
    '8/15',
    '11/2',
    '13/2',
    '7/2'
);
$result = compute($stake, $odds);
var_dump($result);
```

Here's is a working demo you can play with: http://3v4l.org/RNAGH

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you @pomeh I was doing .= then putting the * in, Hence my PHP Errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I feel like you will get unpredictable behaviour with PHP's type juggling, so splitting up the fraction strings using explode will be the best way

```
function calculate($stake, $odds)
{
    $res = $stake;
    foreach ($odds as $odd) {
        $split = explode('/', $odd);
        $res *= ($split[0] / $split[1]) + 1;
    }
    return $res;
}
echo calculate(10, $odds);
```

Comment: @AbraCadaver Corrected the misnamed variable

Answer (score 1):

You mean this way

```
 $stake = 10;
 $odds = array(
 '8/15',
 '11/2',
 '13/2',
 '7/2'
 );

 function formula($stake, array $odds){
    $result = $stake;

    foreach ($odds as $odd) {
        $digit = explode('/',$odd);
        $result *=  ($digit[0]/$digit[1] + 1);
    }
    return $result;
 }

 echo formula($stake, $odds);
```

Comment: Was wondering the same, Quite a few people answers have been downvoted

Comment: @StuBlackett hope my answer helps

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I tested your code - the PHP type casting from the fractions produces an incorrect result (`120960`)

Comment: @AbraCadaver because of the php magical type casting :) i edit the answer

Answer (score -1):

Something like this, I suppose

```
$res = stake;
foreach ($odds as $odd) {
    $res *= ((intval(explode("/", $odd)[0]) / intval(explode("/", $odd)[1])) + 1);
}
echo $res;
```

Comment: Several errors.  Looked like Pavascript at first.  Missing $ and missing args.

Comment: I just constantly improving my answer, dont be too fast )))

Comment: You can improve on a correct answer.  Don't post a non-working, non-parsable one to improve.

Comment: Answers like "Because" really help the community!! Thanks for your help @SergeyYarotskiy